# Incrementar objeto à HTTP request

Tags: c#, http-request, request

Estou tentando fazer um request em que eu envio um JSON (POST) e recebo outro, estou fazendo o seguinte: monto/alimento meu objeto e chamo este request:

```
string URLRequest = URL + customer_id + "/cards";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Headers.Add("...");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";
```

Minha pergunta é: como faço para implementar nesse request o Json (ou objeto) que eu montei anteriormente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture o *request stream* e escreva seu JSON nele.

```
var payload = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(seuJson);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
request.Headers.Add("...");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Accept = "application/json";

using(var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
    stream.Write(payload, 0, payload.Length);
```